# What is this syntax with a function from an empty tuple in Julia Flux gradient?

Tags: julia, flux.jl

I can't find a reference documentation for the `gradient` function of Julia Flux, there are only [several tutorial examples.](https://fluxml.ai/Flux.jl/stable/models/basics/#Taking-Gradients)

I understand how `gradient` is used to compute gradients of functions, e.g. the syntax

```
f(x, y) = x^2 + y^2
df(x, y) = gradient(f, x, y)
```

will essentially yield `df(x, y) = (2x, 2y)`. However later the tutorial uses the following syntax without any explanation:

```
gs = gradient(() -> loss(x, y), Flux.params(W, b))
```

I think there are ways to interpret a gradient of `() -> loss(x, y)` from the math point of view, but I am not sure that this is what is going on here. So what is this anonymous function and why was `gradient` designed that way? A link to the full documentation of `gradient` would be appreciated.

Comment: I think I have an open issue for adding the gradient function into the flux docs. I’ll try to follow up on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, the link to `gradient` docs:
https://fluxml.ai/Zygote.jl/dev/#Zygote.gradient

`gradient` knows to return the derivative with respect to variables referenced within a function but not passed as arguments. This is the case in the example in the question. It is called *implicit style* in the manual. The parameters to differentiate are passed in a `Params` typed value. In the example the `Params` is created by helper function `Flux.params`. When using implicit style, the function is passed as a zero-argument function (see manual).

Regarding the syntax itself (irrespective of use with `gradient`):

`() -> loss(x, y)` is an anonymous function (sometimes called a lambda function in functional programming context). Essentially like a regular function, but for one-time use with no need to fret over choosing a name.

The Julia manual link regarding these is https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/functions/#man-anonymous-functions

Here are some more examples:

With 1 parameter: `map(x -> x^2 + 2x - 1, [1, 3, -1])`

With 2 parameters: `(x,y) -> 2*x + y`

With no parameters: `() -> time()`